# JOGL libraries installation

Tags: java, dll, jar, jogl, java-binding

I am trying to install the JOGL libraries into my eclipse. I was fortunate enough to find a question asked on stack overflow for a link towards the download however I couldn't find a up-to-date installation guide on the internet. I have downloaded the jogl-all-platforms zip which looks like this:

[image]

However I'm not sure at all where the jars that I need are.
Reading the Learning Java Binding by Gene Davis, I am guided in the book to include the jogl.jar and the native library called jogl.dll. I have searched all of the folders for these files however I seem to be missing them. Do I have a bad zip? Did the name of the files change from when the author wrote the book?

Here is a print screen of a search for the jogl.jar

[image]

Here is a print screen of a search for the jogl.dll

[image]

My question is how would I be able to install the java binding so that I'm able to follow the code in the book.

Answer (score 0):

You should have looked at the official JogAmp Wiki, especially [here](http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Setting_up_a_JogAmp_project_in_your_favorite_IDE). Moreover, jogl.jar no longer exists in JOGL 2, it has been replaced by jogl-all.jar. Gene's book probably uses JOGL 1 which is no longer maintained, only JOGL 2.x is actively developed and maintained.